# Editing txt file from batch by tokens with similar variables in the string

Tags: batch-file, edit, ini, string

I am trying to edit a simple txt ini file from a batch file without using a utility.

Thanks to code previously posted by *paxdiablo* I can do this with a form of the code below.

However myfile.ini contains variables like **thing** and **newthing**.

I want to edit only the first, and not the second (which includes the string "thing").

I do not want to change/edit the value of **newthing**.

Right now every edit sets the value for *both* variables.

```
@echo off
set init=50M
set max=75M
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in (myfile.ini) do (
    set str1=%%a
    call :morph
    echo !str2!>>myfile_new.ini
    echo !str2!
)
endlocal
goto :eof

:morph
    set str2=
:morph1
    if not "x!str1!"=="x" (
        if "!str1:~0,6!"=="thing=" (
            set str2=!str2!thing="!init!"
            set str1=!str1:~12!
            goto :morph1
        )
        if "!str1:~0,6!"=="thong=" (
            set str2=!str2!thong="!max!"
            set str1=!str1:~12!
            goto :morph1
        )
        set str2=!str2!!str1:~0,1!
        set str1=!str1:~1!
        goto :morph1
    )
    goto :eof
```

myfile.ini

```
thing=xyz
thong=def
newthing=abc
```

Comment: Why are you unwilling to use external tools? `sed` or `awk` could get the job done on a single line (and there are ports of those for windows). You need something to match "start of line" (so you can avoid matching `anotherthing` for `thing`). The only way I can think of would be to prepend something to each line (like an `@`), then check for `@thing` instead of just `thing`, and afterwards get rid of the `@`, but I'm not familiar with the syntax needed for that. Of course, you'd need to use a prefix that can't be part of a variable name, or you'll hit the same issue under another disguise.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. To enable other users to use the batch, preference is to avoid other tools, but it might be inevitable - and certainly easier. Would use CHANGE.COM or EditMe.exe but have not found a 64-bit version (Win2k8). And the txt ini is fixed in format not controlled by me. For prepend would still have to recognize the specific line/string, bit I know that newthing always comes after thing. which might be useful... Is there some way to select the specific string using the formatting of !str1:~0,6!

Comment: Let me clarify the prepending aproach: upon getting each line (into the variable), you prepend the "@" (or whatever marker) to the variable itself (without having to alter the file). Then you can check for `@thing=...`, and you can be assured that it will be the right variable, `newthing` or `@newthing` won't match `@thing`. After replacing the value, you'd strip the `@` from the variable before writing the line back to the file. I'm sorry, but I have never gone deep enough on Windows' batches to provide any advise beyond conceptual suggestions :(

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to be a little bit too complex.
I reduce it so it works, but perhaps I misunderstood your problem.
But this way it can handle the sample strings in `myfile.ini`.

```
@echo off
set init=50M
set max=75M
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in (myfile.ini) do (
    set str1=%%a
    call :morph
    echo !str1!>>myfile_new.ini
    echo !str1!
)
endlocal
goto :eof


:morph
if "!str1:~0,6!"=="thing=" (
    set "str1=thing=!init!"
)
if "!str1:~0,6!"=="thong=" (
    set "str1=thong=!max!"
)
goto :eof
```